# Returning multiple value in python return function

Tags: python-3.x

My function prints the the index of every element in list that is divided by 2 in a given list. I want to know if there is a way to return all the indexes rather than printing?

```
def printEvenIndex(referenceTuple):                     

    for i in referenceTuple:
        if i % 2 ==0:
            indexOfEvenIntegers = referenceTuple.index(i)
            print(indexOfEvenIntegers)
    return indexOfEvenIntegers 



referenceTuple = (6,5,3,4,1)
print(printEvenIndex(referenceTuple))
```

Right now print statement prints 0 ,3 which is valid. 
But return function is returning 3 only. Is there a way to tell return function to return every element that is divisible by 2? I want to return all the index rather than print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a list and append your indexes there:

```
def readEvenIndexes(referenceTuple):  
    """ Named it readEventIndexes, as we are not printing anymore """                   
    indexes = []
    for index, i in enumerate(referenceTuple):
        if i % 2 ==0:
            indexes.append(index)

    return indexes 


referenceTuple = (6,5,3,4,1)
print(readEvenIndexes(referenceTuple))
```